# Erro ao passar URL como parâmetro... JoeBlogs & HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, wordpress

Main

```
namespace ReaderXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var website = LeitorDeXML("http://SITE ORIGEM/").ToArray();
            var total = website.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i < total; i++)
            {
                Postagem(website[i]);
            }
        }
```

Método para a postagem no blog

```
    private static void Postagem(string website)
        {
            try
            {
                //LINK,USER,SENHA WP
                string link = "http://SITE NOVO";
                string username = "user wp";
                string password = "senha wp";

                //Leitura do HTML
                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument resultat = web.Load(website);

                //Separar TITULO e CONTEUDO
                string titulopost = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-title')]")[0].InnerHtml;
                string conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]")[0].InnerHtml; //ERRO AQUI

                //Entrada no wp
                var wp = new WordPressWrapper(link + "/xmlrpc.php", username, password);
                var post = new Post();

                //Categoria -- Não está funcionando ainda a parte da criação da categoria

                int website_corpo = 25;
                string categoria = website.Substring(website_corpo);
                int indexof_barra = categoria.IndexOf("/");
                int comeco_cat = 0;
                string categoria_f = categoria.Substring(comeco_cat, indexof_barra);

                //Data

                post.DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);

                //Postagem
                post.Title = titulopost;
                post.Body = conteudo;

                wp.NewPost(post, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O método "LeitorDeXML" lê um sitemap declarado no MAIN e me retorna as ultimas urls.

O problema é que quando vou passar esta url como parâmetro, na hora dele pegar o "string conteudo" ele não passa de lá.

Da o seguinte erro:

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object

Comment: Tem como postar o código do método LeitorDeXML

Comment: Você está tentando acessar uma propriedade de um objeto que não foi definido, ou é null.

Answer (score 1):

Você está carregando o html nesta linha abaixo, para simular o problema, precisaria do conteúdo da variável "website".
`HtmlDocument resultat = web.Load(website);`

De toda forma, parece que o xpath passado abaixo não encontra o elemento no HTML e você está tentando acessar o primeiro índice
`string conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]")[0].InnerHtml;`

Você pode confirmar se o xpath não encontrou nada com este código
`int totalEntryContent = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]").Count;`

Se quiser ajuda para resolver o xpath, compartilhe o conteúdo da variável website.

Answer (score 0):

A linha de código

```
string conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]")[0].InnerHtml;
```

aparentemente não está encontrando a div entry-content na página. Verifique se esta div realmente existe na página. Caso não exista, então esse é o motivo dela não estar sendo encontrada.

Contudo, se a div entry-content realmente existe, então o problema está no código que seleciona essa div.

Tente localizar a div por meio da forma indicada abaixo, com linq. Ele busca na página uma div cujo atributo class contenha "entry-content":

```
var conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("entry-content") )[0].InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de realizar a requisição o parâmetro deve ser codificado em Base64. Ao obter o parâmetro da requisição faça o decode do parâmetro com Base64 também.

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar falando besteira, mas tente colocar ex:

```
var website = LeitorDeXML(new Uri("http://SITE ORIGEM/")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente como é o código que você está usando pra ler o xml, mas você pode usar a biblioteca System.Xml para fazer isso rápidamente:

```
String URLString = " http://seu.site.com/SiteMap.xml";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (URLString);
```

Leia mais sobre esta solução em [PROCEDIMENTOS: Ler dados XML em um URL usando o Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/307643)